# Intel GMA500 poor video performance on my Asus 1015cx

Tags: eee-pc, ultrabook, intel-gma

have been Install Ubuntu 14.04 for about 5 months ago on my ASUS Eee PC 1015cx. and I use Flashback-metacity to increase performance. every boot time there always message gma500 trying to get vblank count for disabled pipe. and video performa is poor event playing 2D games. any idea. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

sorry to tell you this, but the gma500 (gpu from intel) has a very bad support on linux, since the drivers for windows where developed by a thirdparty company which refused to write drivers for linux. you wont get any better support. im stuck with a gma by myself and all i can tell you is, that you should get windows.